# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "notizia" does not exist, yet table exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.3

The following error:

```
Notizia.count
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "notizia" does not exist
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"notizia"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"notizia"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

is being generated when trying to access the table data.
`psql` command `\dt` does show that

```
 public | notizias                      | table | me
```

exists. Migration runs smoothly:

```
class CreateNotizias < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :notizias do |t|
      t.date :data
```

[...]

```
==  CreateNotizias: migrating =================================================
-- create_table(:notizias)
   -> 0.0067s
-- add_index(:notizias, :data)
   -> 0.0028s
==  CreateNotizias: migrated (0.0097s) ========================================
```

Loading the data from a pg_dump back-up passes without errors.  Loading via CSV also runs without error when loading via addition.  But if I first delete existing set

```
Notizia.delete_all
```

We get error as above with specified action as:

```
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "notizia"
                    ^
: DELETE FROM "notizia"
```

The thing that stumps me is why is it stating RELATION does not exist when the query is on a single table.  Where is that coming from?

Context: Migration of a rails2 site to rails3.  Of 44 models, this is the only one with a hang-up.

Comment: Um, `notizia` is not the same as `notizias`. You're getting bitten by Rails's frustrating requirements about singular vs plural names.

Comment: ouch. However my syntax is OK for the create_table migration. the table is named appropriately in postgresql...  so there is a conversion problem.  This did not occur in the rails2 version.  So something must have changed in the inflections.  Worst part of it is that I NEVER liked the rails overrides (nor playing with inflectors.rb), so I avoid them by using a neutral nomenklatura.  Apparently, I've stepped into the bear trap.  Will give these a different name and edit the dump file accordingly, barring better suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid I can't help you there. The Rails/ActiveRecord side is something I try to stay far away from, I don't like Invisible Magic That Just Works (until it doesn't, then you can't debug it to save your life).

Comment: I went with a change of model name.  Issues out of the way. I do see the logic with singular and plural naming conventions.  can't put on rails's shoulders the problems of the English language! But yes, some of this stuff could be out in the open or simple rules like just-an-extra-s (where, oh where could notizia trip me up?).  Enough ranting... onward!

Answer (score 0):

Friend, i was having the same problem here.

In my case, this problem was occurring because of incompatibility of gem "rake" in my project.

```
$ gem list | grep rake 
rake (0.9.6, 0.9.2.2)
```

I was using two versions of the gem like you can see above, and my project needed version 0.9.2.2

I was having this problem when running the tests with rspec, so i fixed this using this:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/
```

But if your case was not time to running the tests, just try to run it with "bundle exec" command, for example:

```
bundle exec rails console
```

or,

```
bundle exec "your task"
```

I fixed my problem using this.